# angularFire get $id from nested object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

i have a situation where i have to put nested `ng-repeat`, when i am trying to get the `$id` of first `ng-repeat` i got it without any problem, but when i tried to get the `$id` of second `ng-repeat` (marked red in picture below) i `got undefined`.

my `Firebase` structure is as follows

[image]

here is `items` object
[image: items object]

HTML Code and Controller are here

```js
angular
  .module('starter')
  .controller('feedController', function($scope, $firebaseRef, $firebaseArray) {

    $scope.allRequests = $firebaseArray($firebaseRef.requests);

    $scope.allRequests.$loaded(function() {
      console.log(arguments);
    })

  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<span ng-repeat="items in allRequests">   
    <!-- this works fine -->
      {{items.$id}}
      
      <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        
       <!-- getting undefined here... -->
      {{item.$id}}
      
    </div>
 </span>
```

i need `$id`of second `ng-repeat`, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you show an example of what `items` look like ?

Comment: @VonD i updated my question, please see `items`

Comment: a little offtopic advice: you should not use block elements like `div` inside inline elements like `span`

Comment: @Lulylulu thanks, i'll look into it, but my first priority is to solve this issue.

Comment: @Aamirshah what you printed is the `items` object or you `allRequests` object ?
Are you looking for the id `0347a3c0-..` or the `KFJek...` ?

Comment: @Lulylulu i'm looking for the `KFJek...` key

Comment: ok, so look at @VonD's answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `(key, value)` syntax to iterate over your items :

```
<div ng-repeat="(id, item) in items">
  {{id}}
  {{item.userName}}
</div>
```

What happens is that the `$id` and `$priority` are injected by angularfire on the node on which you made the request. It doesn't inject it in all the sub-nodes of this node, so your individual items do not have a `$id` property.

When you call `ng-repeat="item in items"`, as `items` is an object, angular will iterate over your object's properties, and silently ignore the ones starting with `$`, because this prefix is often used internally by angular. This is a side-effect that angularfire takes advantage of (otherwise, in your `item in items` loop, you would iterate over `$id` and `$priority`). The `(key, value) in object` syntax gives you access to your child object's key.

Comment: Always wondered why this works. Thanks for the great explanation!